# strcpy stack smashing with enough memory allocated

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I'm getting a stack smashing error when running the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME 12
#define MAX_DIR 10

struct Node {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    struct Node *subdirs[MAX_DIR];
};

int mkdir(struct Node* root, char* path) {
   char current_path[MAX_NAME+1];
   strcpy(current_path, path);

   char *next_path = strchr(current_path+1, '/');
   char *token;

   if (!next_path) {
       int i = 0;
       while(i < MAX_DIR && root->subdirs[i]) ++i;
       token = strtok(path, "/");
       root->subdirs[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
       strcpy(root->subdirs[i]->name, current_path+1);
       return 1;
   }

   token = strtok(path, "/");

   while( token != NULL) {

      for(int i = 0; i < MAX_DIR; i++) {
          if (root->subdirs[i] && !strcmp(root->subdirs[i]->name, token))
              return mkdir(root->subdirs[i], next_path);
      }

      token = strtok(NULL, "/");
   }

   printf("not found\n");

   return 0;
}

int main() {
    char input1[] = "/test";
    char input2[] = "/test/bar";
    char input3[] = "/lib/bar";
    char input4[] = "/foo";
    char input5[] = "/test/bar/foaa";

    struct Node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    mkdir(root, input1);
    mkdir(root, input2);
    mkdir(root, input5);

    return 0;
}
```

The code tries to imitate a mkdir command, for the input "/test/bar/foaa", it will create foaa under /test/bar/ if both /test/ and /test/bar/ exist.

The problem is related to this line:

```
       strcpy(root->subdirs[i]->name, current_path+1);
```

as increasing the constant `MAX_NAME` to 15 solves the stack smashing.
Yet, "foaa" is only 5 chars including the \0. So, theoretically, there is plenty space for the strcpy.

What's wrong with my assumptions / code?

Comment: *Yet, "foaa" is only 5 chars*  Why do you focus on `foaa` if you copy the whole string `"/test/bar/foaa"`  into `current_path` which can only hold 12 bytes (including 0 byte).

Comment: I'd bet  `MAX_NAME` and  `MAX_DIR` are too small. Have you even tried to debug this?

Comment: ... and you never initialize the struct `root` points to. Be aware that the content of memory allocated by `malloc` is undetermined, if can contain anything.

Comment: `strcpy()` is rarely useful, use `strncpy()` or `strlcpy()` (or something similar) if available, unless it really is what you need.

Comment: You should be directly copying a substring from `path`, not double-copying to `current_path`, which probably doesn't have enough space.

Comment: @JohnBayko `strncpy` can be just as dangerous as `strcpy` since there are cases where the former will not terminate the string.

Comment: @SafelyFast Yes. Unfortunately `strncpy()` is an established standard function, better alternatives are mostly not. `sprintf()` might be the best portable alternative, but it's still abusable/sometimes tricky. So my point was at least look at alternatives, and `strncpy()` can at least limit some damage, and if you can remember to add the missing '\0' on the next line it can be safe.